# Database model validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I want to add a validation in my model where I have 2 fields:

```
t.boolean :first
t.boolean :second
```

I want to ensure that when

```
first field is false
```

then

```
second field is always false
```

Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this in Rails3:

```
class MyValidator < ActiveModel::EachValidator
  def validate_each(object, attribute, value)
    unless {your condition here}
      object.errors[attribute] << (options[:message] || "your error here") 
    end
  end
end
```

Edit: Forgot to mention that this example is from Railscasts: http://railscasts.com/episodes/211-validations-in-rails-3 in case you need more detailed information on this topic

Comment: What is the advantage of using a new class instead of a method like all the others suggested?

Comment: Class is reusable and more readable, other solutions will lead to copy-paste (eventually).

Answer (score 2):

```
validate :if_first_is_false_second_is_also
def if_first_is_false_second_is_also
  if self.first_field == false && self.second_field != false
    errors.add(:second_field, "your error message")
  end
end
```

[More on validations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html)

Answer (score 1):

I assume here that when `first` is `true`, it's always ok.

```
validate :check_booleans

def check_booleans
  if first == false
     errors[:base] << "wrong here" if second == true
  end
end
```

Comment: Validations do not check return values, you need to add errors to the object: `self.errors.add(:second, "can't be false")`